# NLP - Combining Words of same meaning into One

Tags: r, nlp, tm

I am quite new to NLP. My question is can I combine words of same meaning into one using NLP, for example, considering the following rows;

```
1. It’s too noisy here
2. Come on people whats up with all the chatter
3. Why are people shouting like crazy
4. Shut up people, why are you making so much noise
```

As one can notice, the common aspect here is that the people are complaining about the noise.

```
noisy, chatter, shouting, noise -> Noise
```

Is it possible to group the words using a common entity using NLP. I am using R to come up with a solution to this problem.

I have used a sample twitter data set and my expected output will be a table which contains;

```
 Noise
It’s too noisy here
Come on people whats up with all the chatter
Why are people shouting like crazy
Shut up people, why are you making so much noise
```

I did search the web for reference before posting here. Any suggestion or valuable inputs will be of much help.

Thanks

Comment: how does the data-format look like? is it a list, json .... please provide an example.

Comment: @ Andre Elrico, the data is in CSV format.

Comment: the `grepl` function is your friend with a pattern of `"noisy|chatter|shouting|noise"`

Comment: #regularExpressions

Answer (score 2):

The problem you mention is  better known as paraphrasing, and it is not completetly solved. Maybe if you want a fast solution, you can start replacing synonyms, [wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) can help with that.

Other idea is calculate sentence similarity (just getting a vector representation of each sentence and use cosine distance to measure similarity to each other)

I think [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d020/eb83f03a9f9c97e728355c4a9010fa65d8ef.pdf) could provide a good introduction for your problem.